# Render partial later after page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. Let's say I have the following view:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <h1><%= @shop.name %></h1>
    <p><%= @shop.description %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <%= render 'teasers' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to just load the page first, then load the `teasers` later? Reason being so is because `teasers` takes some time to query (I have already optimized the query).

Comment: Yeah, looking at that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personaly have a pre-defined system for this kind of behavior:

This (coffeescript) Javascript code is executed at each rendering of a page:

```
$('.ajax_load').each (index, element) ->
  e = $(element)
  $.get e.data('url'), (data) =>
    $(document).replace(e, data)
```

So each element in my page responding to the class "ajax_load" is actually called by ajax, example:

```
%div.ajax_load{ data: { url: users_path } }
```

This will display at first a div with a class ajax_load, and will send a request to `users_path` and replace the div with the response's content.

---

This is translated coffeescript:

```
$('.ajax_load').each(function(index, element) {
  var e,
    _this = this;
  e = $(element);
  return $.get(e.data('url'), function(data) {
    return $(document).replace(e, data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the teasers partial from the view and initially just displaying the page without it.  Then using javascript, make an AJAX call to the server.

You can use [wiselinks](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks) to simplify your life.